# make a side_effect iterator loop over from "beginning to end" "over and over again"

Tags: python, mocking, python-2.7

I must say I am new to **python mock**.
I have an **side_effect iterator**:

```
myClass.do.side_effect = iter([processStatus, memoryStatus, processStatus, memoryStatus, processStatus, memoryStatus, processStatus, memoryStatus])
```

*The above works as expected and the test cases pass*

But I am looking for a better way to write this.
I tried `[....]*4` which did not work.

How should I do it? Simply, making the iterator to start from the beginning once it come to the end.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, that feel like a dirty hack. I would need to do that a couple of times.

Comment: What is `processStatus`?  A function?  Something stateful?  I'm a little surprised that `iter([pS, mS]*4)` wouldn't work.

Comment: @DSM those are the output parameters for the mocked functions. The error I got is that an iterator can not be multiplied by an integer value.

Comment: @Alborz -- that's because you're writing `iter([ ... ])*4` instead of `iter([...]*4)` -- Iterator's can't be multiplied by integers, but *lists* can.  So, you just make an iterator out of a longer list and you're all set.  however, if DSM undelete's his answer, `itertools.cycle` or `itertools.repeat` is probably a better way to go about doing this.

Comment: @mgilson, thanks it works with [...]*4 but there is a constant there now which I dislike ;)  can you elaboarte more on the use of itertools.repeat!

Comment: @Alborz -- I think you probably actually want `itertools.cycle` (although it's a little difficult to say).  See the answer posted by DSM.  I think it will be helpful. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use `itertools.cycle` here, if you want 'over and over again':

```
>>> s = range(3)
>>> s
[0, 1, 2]
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> c = cycle(s)
>>> c
<itertools.cycle object at 0xb72697cc>
>>> [next(c) for i in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]
>>> c = cycle(['pS', 'mS'])
>>> [next(c) for i in range(10)]
['pS', 'mS', 'pS', 'mS', 'pS', 'mS', 'pS', 'mS', 'pS', 'mS']
```

Or, as @mgilson notes, if you want a finite number of 2-element terms (I'm not completely sure of what data format you need):

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> repeat([2,3], 3)
repeat([2, 3], 3)
>>> list(repeat([2,3], 3))
[[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

But as noted in the comments, `iter([1,2,3]*n)` should work too.

Comment: I tried this and it works, but I need to call next(). What I need  is a looping-iterator to supply to the side_effect function.

Comment: The cycle object *is* a looping iterator.  `cycle([pS, mS])` is just like `iter([pS, mS]*4)` but instead of 4 it's infinity.  I just used `next` to extract some values (I could have used `itertools.islice` too).

Comment: this is brilliant thanks. i used this method to mock googleapiclient as one of the clients requires a `nextPageToken` (bool) to stop iteration which is fine unless the code is embedded in another nested loop.